# Assertion failure _setName.size on URI auth

Tags: mongodb

I tried to much posibilities that I found searching for this error without success.

I can connect to my mongo with the CLI typing `mongo --port myPort -u myUser ...`

But I need to connect my app (in the same host) by URI.
This is what I get:

```
mongo mongodb://username:password@localhost:myPort/myDb


MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: mongodb://username:password@localhost:myPort/myDb
2017-05-19T23:34:33.568+0200 Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 231
2017-05-19T23:34:33.569+0200 0x6b75c9 0x659e9f 0x636a32 0x5013b8 0x4fa7f1 0x6006fd 0x5eb869 0x7fdcdff35d76 0x1ebf47506362
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x39) [0x6b75c9]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x21f) [0x659e9f]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x142) [0x636a32]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionStringC1ENS0_14ConnectionTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_+0x208) [0x5013b8]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionString5parseERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERS6_+0x201) [0x4fa7f1]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo17mongoConsExternalEPNS_7V8ScopeERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0x11d) [0x6006fd]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo7V8Scope10v8CallbackERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0xa9) [0x5eb869]
 /usr/lib/libv8.so.3.14.5(+0x99d76) [0x7fdcdff35d76]
 [0x1ebf47506362]
2017-05-19T23:34:33.570+0200 Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:231 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

Any idea? :\ Thanks

Comment: try to use --host<> --port<>  --db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved upgrading mongod from 2.6 to 3.0.15

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade to a newer version of MongoDB you can also just drop the `mongodb://` from the beginning. For example change:

`mongo mongodb://username:password@localhost:myPort/myDb`

to:

`mongo username:password@localhost:myPort/myDb`

Ref: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15739?focusedCommentId=1000536&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1000536